# doing a where() after a get()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to add a new feature to an existing Laravel codebase and in that codebase there's this:

```
    $hasGAP = (new \App\Models\Policy)->where('leadID', $leadId)
        ->where('policystatus', '!=', 'Canceled')
        ->get()->where('product.name', 'GAP Insurance')->count() > 1;
```

So this is doing an SQL query on the table referenced by the `\App\Models\Policy` model. It's doing `WHERE policystatus != 'Canceled'` and then it's getting the result. And then it's doing a `WHERE` on the result? That doesn't make sense to me.

Also, `product.name` isn't a column in the table. Indeed, it seems like the period (`.`) operator would be an illegal character..

Does this code actually work and if so what is it actually doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `->get()` ends the query and returns the results in a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections).

The subsequent [`->where(..)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-where) and [`->count()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-count) are then calls on the collection.

The dot notation is widely used in Laravel for getting sub fields of arrays, objects and similar data structures (example: [array_get()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-get)) and works in `->where()` (on a collection) as well.

So the posted code *should* work. I assume the `Policy` belongsTo (or hasOne) a product and the dot notation is used to search by the related product name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the toQuery()

Example:

```
collection = Model::where(...)->get()
collection2 = collection->toQuery()->where(...)->get()
```

https://readouble.com/laravel/8.x/ja/eloquent-collections.html#method-toquery